# is there a way to have database columns independent of each other?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm kinda new so this might be an easy one but this is my database model

```
class Custom(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value1 = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = True)
    value2 = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = True)
    value3 = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = True)
    value4 = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable = True)
```

lets assume i do

```
Custom(value1 = 'cake is nice')
```

all the other columns will be filled in as None.
is there a way to avoid that? and have the other values empty instead of None.

Comment: `None` is essentially empty.  It's the Python equivalent of `NULL` in a SQL database.  I don't see why you'd want anything different.

Comment: when i query the database it looks like [None, None, value]. instead i want it to be just [value] as i use them as strings, is there a way to skip over the None while iterating?

Comment: You can write a repr or str method on your class that concatentates them for display. The values themselves are unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you never have more than 1 value per row, you better create just 3 tables in your database like in this example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

class model1(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.String(30))

class model2(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.String(30))

class model3(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.String(30))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `None` itself is empty but since you dont like to have `None`. In that case you have a default value that is set to empty string as your columns are string.

```
class Custom(db.Model):
 id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
 value1 = db.Column(db.String(30), server_default='')
 value2 = db.Column(db.String(30), server_default='')
 value3 = db.Column(db.String(30), server_default='')
 value4 = db.Column(db.String(30), server_default='')
```